# NSMutableArray to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This could be a silly question but I am new to IPhone developing, anyhow I have an `NSMutableArray` with information loaded from a server. I am trying to put this information on a table. I  searched around for some ideas on how to do this and I ran into this code which a lot of people seem to use in order to do this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath           *)indexPath
  {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSLog(@"Cell is %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
return cell;
```

}

now my question is inside the if statement it gives me two errors with the autorelease saying: is unavailable and not available on reference counting mode, and arc forbids message send of autorelease, any thoughts?? thanks for the help

Comment: Sounds like you are compiling with ARC enabled. If so, remove the `autorelease` call.

Comment: You're blindly copying an example that uses the old style garbage collection but you're building with "ARC" (Automatic Reference Counting) enabled.

Comment: You're useARC mode. Just delete autorealease.

Comment: @HotLicks Since this is iOS, you mean manual reference counting, not garbage collection.

Comment: awesome it compiles now but for some reason nothin is on the table, it gives me a warning where i declare the cell saying local declaration of tableView hides instance variable could that be the issue?

Comment: If it didn't collect garbage there'd be no point in counting the references.

Comment: @paul590 Is your view controller based on `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`? It sounds like you added your own table view and you have an instance variable named `tableView`. The warning is telling you that the local variable (parameter) `tableView` will be used instead of the instance variable with the same name.

Comment: Most likely there's nothing in the table because there's nothing in myArray.  NSLog that (inside numberOfRowsInSection).  This will also make sure that numberOfRowsInSection is even getting called.

Comment: @HotLicks iOS have never supported garbage collection.

Comment: (Change the tableView parameter name to "tableViewParm" to get rid of the warning.)

Comment: Correction: Never (prior to ARC) supported *automatic* garbage collection.

Comment: its a UIViewController and i added the table manually, is there anyway to make it use the instance variable?

Comment: BTW, your error had nothing  to do with NSMutableArray or UITableView.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have is older code and only works as-is with manual reference counting (MRC). Newer projects use automatic reference counting (ARC) by default. Just remove the call to `autorelease` and you will be fine.

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using Automatic Reference Counting, which takes care of memory management for you (for the most part). Remove all references to manual memory management, such as `autorelease` (and `retain`, `release`, etc.), and the app will build. Use this here below:

```
if (!cell) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also easily done using the freely available Sensible TableView framework. They have something called ArrayOfObjectsSection where you just pass the NSArray to and it will display it automatically, amongst many other stuff (including doning the server fetching for you).

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple tutorial link for add a NSMutableArray into the tableView...[Simple Tutorial link](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/02/21/table-view-tutorial-part-2-populate-a-table-view-with-an-nsmutablearray/)..Hope Its useful for you.